# Angular: ControlValueAccessor vs @Input - When to use what with forms?

Tags: angular

ControlValueAccessors popped up to me over the last months and I'm a bit confused on why or when I should use them instead of using `@Input` with my reactive forms.

Here's a sample code for how I've worked with reactive forms so far:

```js
@Component({
 selector: 'app-my-component',
 template: `<input [formControl]="form.get('specificControlName')"  />` 
 // or the alternative method of [formGroup]="form" and formControlName="specificControlName"
})
export class MyComponent {
 @Input() form: FormGroup; // passed in formGroup

 ngOnInit() {
  form.valueChanges.pipe(
   // do rxjs magic here
  ).subscribe(value => {
   // do something with the value
  })
 }
}
```

Reactive Forms save the state of the form, so I can access that state even from the parent components. I can also access all the different `NgControl` attributes like `valid`, `disabled`, `dirty`, and `touched`.

What do ControlValueAccessors provide that this way of working with reactive forms don't? And what are some use cases where ControlValueAccessors work better than `@Input` and `@Output` in general?

**EDIT**:

https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/angular-nested-reactive-forms-using-cvas-b394ba2e5d0d

In this article the author mentions the following as the main differences:

> Three Ways to implement nested forms:
>
> ...
>
> 2. By passing a handle of the FormGroup to child components via Input and referencing it in child templates. There are couple of good tutorials on it.
>
> But the con of using this approach is that you are tightly binding the parent form group with that of child group.
>
> 3. Using Composite CVAs.
>
> Pros: Highly Reusable, Portable. Better Encapsulation(Internal Form Controls of the component doesn’t necessarily need to be visible to parent components). This is best used when you have more number of form modules which is typically a large project.
>
> Cons: Need to implement CVA interface results in boilerplate code.

This is interesting, but it raises a couple of more questions: Why and when do you not want your internal Form Controls to be visible to the parent? What does portable mean?

Also:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor,NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, NG_VALIDATORS, FormGroup,FormControl, Validator, Validators,AbstractControl, ValidationErrors } from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-address-info',
  templateUrl: './address-info.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./address-info.component.css']
})
export class AddressInfoComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {

public addressForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
  addressLine: new FormControl("",[Validators.required]),
  areacode: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(5)])
});
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {
  }

  public onTouched: () => void = () => {};

  writeValue(val: any): void {
    val && this.addressForm.setValue(val, { emitEvent: false });
  }
  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    console.log("on change");
    this.addressForm.valueChanges.subscribe(fn);
  }
  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    console.log("on blur");
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }
  setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    isDisabled ? this.addressForm.disable() : this.addressForm.enable();
  }
}
```

when you're passing in a `FormGroup` into a `ControlValueAccessor` Component the author is initializing a new `FormGroup` inside of the component with the same structure as the passed in object. Isn't it better then to just pass in the `FormGroup` itself then? Or what benefits does the encapsulation provide?

EDIT2: This is an interesting video on the subject:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CD_t3m2WMM8

Comment: check this:https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/never-again-be-confused-when-implementing-controlvalueaccessor-in-angular-forms-93b9eee9ee83

Comment: I would say there's no hard rule on this. As powerful as reactive forms are [this github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/31963) lists some of the short comings of reactive forms, a big one being that they are not strongly typed. *Why do you not want your internal Form Controls to be visible to the parent?* .,,because this provides separation of concerns. Say you have 4 input boxes but the parent only cares about the concatenated value separated by spaces (think credit card number). I've personally settled on using @Input, patchValue and the ngOnChanges hook.

Answer (score 2):

> Use Standard Reactive Form API whenever you are using native HTML
>   elements (input, select, button, form, etc)
>
> Use ControlValueAccessor for example when you have to work with custom
>   HTML elements (i.e. mat-list, mat-table, ag-grid-table, etc), the
>   reason is because it's an interface that acts as a **bridge** between
>   Angular forms API and DOM elements. [ControlValueAccessor example](https://alligator.io/angular/custom-form-control/)